# How to set onclicklistener to Drawable on canvas?

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-drawable

I do not have imageview,I have drwable and I draw it on canvas like this:

```
drawable.draw(canvas);
```

How can I set onclicklistener to drawable ?
I use this project : https://code.google.com/p/android-multitouch-controller/

(I want to use on click listener because I want to remove drawable on canvas)
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A drawable does not have any facility to receive events or otherwise interact with the user. It's just a visual response as far as the android os is concerned and is often used as fetched resource.

You might be better off creating a [view](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html). Then override the

```
onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)
```

But if you must, consider the **getBounds** in your endeavours.

Comment: I want to use on click listener because I want to remove drawable on canvas

Comment: then perhaps in the nearest view you handle the input checking if the touch point is within the getBounds, delete if so.

Comment: I want to need on long listener or on long touch listener, because I want to delete that drawable ?